# Why is Express.js listening on two ports under WSL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Express is set to listen on port `9999`, when the message `Listening on http://localhost:9999` appears in the terminal and I click on it, it opens a web browser to `http://localhost:10000`.

Both port `9999` and `10000` are responding to requests.

Code:

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 9999;
const host = "localhost";

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

const server = app.listen(port, host, () => {
  const url = `http://${host}:${server.address().port}`;
  console.log(`Listening on ${url}`);
});
```

terminal:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9999
Hello World
$ curl http://localhost:10000
Hello World
```

This seems to be specific to running it on Windows 10 WSL. Running this in a native Debian environment didn't produce the same result.

What is happening here? Is this a WSL thing?

Comment: Are both ports listening for same node process pid? `ss -lntp`

Comment: This is hard to answer because ss isn't supported on WSL. I can see a single process (using `ps a`) for `npm` that I have started (inside WSL). Outside in Windows, I can run NETSTAT.EXE -abo and see two processes on both ports.

Comment: hmm, sorry I don't have a wsl box handy. You should see at least 2 processes when running something via `npm`. Both `npm` and the `node` or whatever process it starts.

Comment: Maybe just wait a couple of weeks for wsl2. Most of the strangeness will go away :)

Comment: I can start the process without npm by `node index.js`. I can see a single `node` process when doing `ps a`.